# All IIS7 sites resolve to railo default installation page

Tags: tomcat, iis, coldfusion, iis-7, railo

After a new railo 4.2 install on win/IIS7, all sites seem to default to Railo new installation page. Is there a quick and easy way to disable/enable specific sites to use the IIS connector? Is Railo supposed to nbe hijacking all requests and directing to the 'Welcome to Railo world!' page in the first place?

I have a couple CF sites, and a bunch of non-cf sites, so railo is configured to start manually - only when I need to to perform CF work. Otherwise, I'd like the connector to stay out of my biz. thoughts?

Comment: How did you perform your install? What connector did you use? Was your Windows OS a new build or were you upgrading an old one?

Comment: Fresh OS, BonCodeAJP13 connector, Wndows stand-alone installer (4.2.008-pIO-windows-installler.exe), install went smoothly. I'm thinking it has something to do with routing, here is an example:

- hosts file contains  "mytestsite     127.0.0.1"
- Before railo install, site worked at http://mytestsite
 - After railo install, resolves to railo welcome page, even though in IIS it's physical path is C:\inetroot\mytestsite.
However, it should be noted that if I use a virtual directory off the default web site, it will work corrrectly (http://localhost/inetroot/mytestsite,  inetroot is C:\inetroot\)

Comment: I wonder if the virtual directory you mentioned is throwing off mod_cfml - the "glue" that adds new hosts to Tomcat automatically. Try adding the host manually to the C:\railo\tomcat\conf\server.xml file. File is heavily commented at the bottom, so you should see how to add a host manually there.

You can add a virtual dir to the manual config like this:

 <Host name="lucee.org" appBase="webapps">
   <Context path="" docBase="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\" />
   <Context path="/virtualdir" docBase="C:\someotherdir\virtualdir\" />
   <Alias>www.lucee.org</Alias>
   <Alias>my.lucee.org</Alias>
 </Host>

Comment: bah... formatting doesn't work in comments, but you get the idea I hope. ;)